# Making a shape from characters in an array in c

Tags: c

I would like to return a shape(trapezium) with bases 6 and 3 given integers 3 and 4 and a char.

I have tried implementing this with code below but I am getting a rectangle instead

```
#include <stdio.h>

char my_array[];
char *ptr;
int m = 3,n =4;

int main(void)
{
int i,j;
ptr = &my_array[0];

for (j = 0;j < n ;++j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < m+n-1; i++)
        {
            my_array[i] = '*';
            printf("%c ",my_array[i]);

        }
            printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
```

}

I would like to know how I can reduce the length of each row of the result above to get the shape i need.Any ideas?

Comment: You should add an example of your desired output, and what you currently get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to use `i < m + j - 1` in your second for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int m = 3, n = 4;

int main(void){
    int i, j;
    const char symb = '*';

    for (j = 0; j < n ;++j){    
        for (i = 0; i < m + j - 1; i++)
            printf("%c ",symb);

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sure ,i wanted     'i < m + j - 1'